# Can I solve $\lim_{(x,y)\to\ (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+x^2y^2+y^2}$ by converting to polar coordinates?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, limits-without-lhopital

Is it correct to solve this problem like this?
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\ (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+x^2y^2+y^2} $$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\ (0,0)} \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2y^2}}$$
$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2y^2}=\lim_{r\to\ 0} \frac{1}{r^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}=\infty\implies \lim_{(x,y)\to\ (0,0)} \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2y^2}}=0$$

Comment: It is almost correct! See how you can avoid $0$ in the denominators.

Comment: That direct line of reasoning isn't right, but you can modify it without the intermediate "infinite" limit.

Comment: Thanks, but why the intermediate step is wrong ? 1 divided by something that goes to zero is infinity or ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly by polar we obtain

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+x^2y^2+y^2}=\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta}{1+ r^2\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta}\to \frac{0}{1+0}=0$$

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to make it more complicated. Simply observe that $x^2 \le x^2+x^2y^2+y^2\implies \dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+x^2y^2+y^2} \le y^2\implies \text{limit} = 0$ .